# HashSet UnionWith() method's performance problems in C#

Tags: c#, performance, list, hashset

I have have many `HashSet` that contain different index exceptions. I combine these hashsets into one big `HashSet` depending on the input data. For testing purposes I've also ported `HashSet` into `List` analogues.

- The sole purpose of `HashSet` and `List` is to exclude indexes from random number generation.

That's what I do in List's case:

```
list2 = new List<int>();
for (int d = 0; d < list1.Count; d++)
{
  if (dicCat4[30].ContainsKey(list1[d]))
  {
    list2.AddRange(dicCat4[30][list1[d]]);
  }
}

rand = 2 * RandString.Next(0 / 2, (dicCat[30].Count) / 2);
while (list2.Contains(rand))
{
  rand = 2 * RandString.Next(0 / 2, (dicCat[30].Count) / 2);
}
// action with random
```

As you can see all exceptions (indexes) are merged into one list using `AddRange()`. With `Contains()` method we check if the random number is within a list or not.

The same operation can be done with HashSet:

```
excludehash = new HashSet<int>();

for (int d = 0; d < list1.Count; d++)
{
  if (dicCat4[30].ContainsKey(list1[d]))
  {
    excludehash.UnionWith(dicCat3[30][list1[d]]);
  }
}

rand = 2 * RandString.Next(0 / 2, (dicCat[30].Count) / 2);
while (excludehash.Contains(rand))
{
  rand = 2 * RandString.Next(0 / 2, (dicCat[30].Count) / 2);
}
// action with random
```

in this case, instead of `AddRange()` I use `UnionWith()` method to merge the `HashSet` of index exceptions.

Strangely, after thousands of iterations - **overall performance of `List` method is better!** , but according to many sources `HashSet` should perform faster. Performance profiler showed that the largest performance hog is HashSet's `UnionWith()` method.

I'm just curious - **is there any way how to make `HashSet` solution perform faster?** (quick idea just occurred to me: as an alternative I can use `Contains(rand)` on every separate hashset, hence skipping `UnionWith()` method)

P.S. hashsets and lists are retrieved from:

```
static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>> dicCat3;
static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<int>>> dicCat4;
```

**EDIT: hardcore iteration solution**

```
int inter = list1.Count;
int cco = 0;

while (inter != cco)
{
  cco = 0;

  rand = 2 * RandString.Next(0 / 2, (dicCat[30].Count) / 2);

  for (int d = 0; d < list1.Count; d++)
  {
    if (dicCat4[30].ContainsKey(list1[d]))
    {
      if (!dicCat3[30]][list1[d]].Contains(rand))
      {
        cco++;
      }
      else
      {
        break;
      }
   }
   else
   {
     cco++;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: 2 is needed to generate **even** numbers only. 0 means that the minimal range is 0 (zero). Maximum is (dicCat[30].Count). i.e. rand = [from 0 to (dicCat[30].Count)]

Comment: Well, List.AddRange doesn't check for uniqueness, while HashSet.UnionWith does...

Comment: yes, list has some duplicates

Comment: I mean, since AddRange simply appends the new values to the list, it will be faster than UnionWith that checks also that the added values don't create duplicates (even if not so *much* faster). Anyway, the loop calling Contains should be faster for the HashSet (much faster if called a lot of times).

Comment: @digEmAll can you check my HashSet loop solution (see edit).. I've nearly lost my mind while coding it.. so there might be some mistakes, but it actually performs a little bit faster than a list!

Comment: @Alex: I actually don't know what you want to accomplish, but the loop seems fine to me. And of course Contains is faster for hashsets than for lists (unless the list contains a couple elements only).

Comment: in my case the dictionary of Lists performs faster than the dictionary of HashSets.. note* there are about 20 elements in each list (5-6 lists are being checked, so that's about 100 elements total)

Answer (score 1):

Try use SortedSet instead of HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to gain a little performance on your edit swap your if/else around.  C# assumes that the else clause is more likely, so evaluates that tree first!  You should shave off a couple of ms there.  But other than that I can't see a real way to save you anything!

If you post a solution I can import then I'll happily have a play and see what I can do, but I'm not going to type it all out for fun! ;)

Comment: Hm swapping the if and else branches is such a micro optimization. It is an optimization on the level of the physical processor.

Comment: But if her wants to squeeze every bit of speed out of it that's an improvement! :P

Comment: Is that due to branch predictors?